# Gps latitude and longitude doesn't give me a valid value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geolocation, gps

I have an app that can shoot some photos. Every time I shoot a photo I should send a request with the latitude and longitude of the user so I can know where the photo has been taken.

**So i did something like this to get the location:**

```
public class GoogleLocation implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private double lat;
    private double lon;
    private double alt;

    private Context context;
    LocationManager lm;
    final int  MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION  = 1;

    public GoogleLocation(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }



    public Map<String,String> getPosition() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  },
                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION);
        }

        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER );
        if(location != null){
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lon = location.getLongitude();
            alt = location.getAltitude();
        }
        params.put("lat",String.valueOf(lat));
        params.put("lon",String.valueOf(lon));
        params.put("alt",String.valueOf(alt));
        return params;
    }


    public void location(){
        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = null;
        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
            googleApiClient.connect();

            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
            locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                    .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

            //**************************
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
            //**************************

            PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                    LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                    final Status status = result.getStatus();
                    final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                            // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                            // requests here.
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                            // a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                                status.startResolutionForResult(
                                        (Activity) context, 1000);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

But I always get the default values for the lat lon, 0.0, on my GPS emulator I have some values defined for the GPS, which i would able to get 2 hour ago but I don't know why it stopped working.

How can I get them, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` - Here you are asking for GPS based location, not network based location.

GPS based location means phone needs to have GPS sensor to get the location. Your emulator doesn't have that sensor.

Same thing with `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` - High accuracy means GPS based location. This will not work with emulators.

Solution:
If you want to use emulator for testing, change `GPS_PROVIDER` to `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

OR

use a real phone that has a GPS sensor (most phones these days do).

Comment: Then why the emulator has a gps simulator? if it doesn't work as exptected? strange.

Comment: I did the changes you mentioned and still get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following link helps you : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/